# Obtaining representation of SMT formula as SAT formula

Tags: z3, smt

I've come up with an SMT formula in Z3 which outputs one solution to a constraint solving problem using only BitVectors and IntVectors of fixed length.  The logic I use for the IntVectors is only simple Presburger arithmetic (of the form `(x[i] - x[i + 1] <=/>= z)` for some x and z).  I also take the sum of all of the bits in the bitvector (NOT the binary value), and set that value to be within a range of [a, b].

This works perfectly.  The only problem is that, as z3 works by always taking the easiest path towards determining satisfiability, I always get the same answer back, whereas in my domain I'd like to find a variety of substantially different solutions (I know for a fact that multiple, very different solutions exist).  I'd like to use this nifty tool I found https://bitbucket.org/kuldeepmeel/weightgen, which lets you uniformly sample a constrained space of possibilities using SAT.  To use this though, I need to convert my SMT formula into a SAT formula.

Do you know of any resources that would help me learn how to perform Presburger arithmetic and adding the bits of a bitvector as a SAT instance?  Alternatively, do you know of any SMT solver which as an intermediate step outputs a readable description of the problem as a SAT instance?

Many thanks!

[Edited to reflect the fact that I really do need the uniform sampling feature.]

Comment: also - all integers are <= 64, so I imagine I should be able to use BitVectors for those too!

Comment: To enforce a different answer, you could add the previous solutions as negated constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think this will work - I want a random sampling over the entire (very large) solution space, and my playing around suggests that adding previous solutions just results in small changes

Comment: Z3 does have a bit-blasting tactic, see: https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies. How much "SMT" remains after this tactic, or whether you can save the bit-blasted version to a file is not clear though. I'd say this is definitely not possible via the SMTLib interface, but might be possible using some internal Z3 api call. You can ask at their github site to see if an internal call might be available: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: If you need uniform sampling, WeightGen may not be the tool for you since it is intended for weighted sampling.  UniGen2 (https://bitbucket.org/kuldeepmeel/unigen/) or SPUR (https://github.com/ZaydH/spur - a tool I developed) are designed for uniform SAT sampling.